# how to get selected item store in a text block

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

this is xaml code i have used.

```
   <ListView  x:Name="lvLocations" Grid.Row="1" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            SelectionMode="Single"

               SelectionChanged="lvLocations_SelectionChanged"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
             Margin="19,12,19,0"
             >

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                                FontSize="22"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                Margin="0,12,0,0" 
                                />

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

this is the c# code behind

```
      List<string> locations = new List<string>();

        // If the query returns results then bind it to the list view.
        if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
        {
            foreach (MapLocation mapLocation in result.Locations)
            {
                // create a display string of the map location
                string display = mapLocation.Address.StreetNumber + " " +
                    mapLocation.Address.Street + Environment.NewLine +
                    mapLocation.Address.Town + ", " +
                    mapLocation.Address.RegionCode + "  " +
                    mapLocation.Address.PostCode + Environment.NewLine +
                    mapLocation.Address.CountryCode;

                // add the display string to the location list
                locations.Add(display);
            }

            // bind the location list to the ListView control
            lvLocations.ItemsSource = locations;

        }
```

this code will display string in textblocks and i want when user click on one of the choice it get store in textblock or get bind into other textblock
please suggest me how to do this

Thank you in advance

Comment: private async void lvLocations_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

            addr.Text = lvLocations.SelectedItems.ToString();
        }

Comment: it is givng me exception please  help

Comment: Can you add some more code and elaborate on your issues? I am not clear what exactly you are trying to solve. Where are choices? What Textblock are you talking about?